# Pointcut expression to match all public methods in all classes of my application except few packages and classes

Tags: aop, spring-aop

I want to match all `public` methods of all classes of my application(not the dependency library classes) except one class and except classes in one package.

Kotlin class:

```
  @Pointcut("execution(public * com.company.app..*.*(..))")
  fun allApplicationCode() {}

  @Pointcut("!execution(* * com.company.app.configuration..*.*(..))")
  fun notConfigurationPackage() {}

  @Pointcut("!execution(* * com.company.app..FlywayConfiguration.*(..))")
  fun notFlywayConfigurationClass() {}
  
  @Around("allApplicationCode() && notConfigurationPackage() && notFlywayConfigurationClass()")
  fun logExecutionTime(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint): Any { 
    //code
  }
```

I get error regarding the Pointcut expressions in `notConfigurationPackage()` and `notFlywayConfigurationClass()`

Is it a problem if I want to mention "*" explicitly for access modifier?

Comment: https://jstobigdata.com/spring/pointcut-expressions-in-spring-aop/

Comment: Does your link mean that your problem is solved or not? Please communicate more clearly. If you still have a problem, please edit the question and post the full error message incl. stack trace.